# Creating the symbol \upupharpoonright

Tags: symbols

I would like to define a new symbol in mathmode, namely `\upupharpoonright`, which concatenates two `\upharpoonright` with no space between them. My attempt  was the following

> `\newcommand{\upupharpoonright}{\upharpoonright\kern-0.2em\upharpoonright}`

And it would work alright, if it wasn't for the fact that sometimes the two `\upharpoonright` are divided (in a line-break e.g.).
How can I make the block of the two consecutive harpoons indivisible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the kern as a math relation symbol, so no line break is possible at it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\upupharpoonright}{%
  \upharpoonright
  \mathrel{\mkern-4.5mu}%
  \upharpoonright
}

\begin{document}

$x\upupharpoonright y$

\end{document}
```

[image]